# How to Substitute Cell Value to TextFile

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new with the VBA. Now I want to practice using a simple problem.

I have a excel file that contains the ff values:

```
Juan    Miguel  28
John    Smith   25
```

I want to substitute these value cell per cell in a text file.

Let's say my text file is something like this:

```
FirstName Person1: $A1
LastName Person1: $B1
Age Person1: $C1

FirstName Person2: $A2
LastName Person2: $B2
Age Person2: $C2
```

Is it possible to have this instead of hardcoding the content of a testfile inside my code using the code below?

```
Print #TextFile, "Hello Everyone!"
```

Comment: Please try this by typing in VBE ~Sub Printtest()
Dim lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
Debug.Print .Cells(i, 1).Text & "   " & .Cells(i, 2).Text & "   "; .Cells(i, 3).Text & "    Hello Everyone! "
Next
End With
End Sub
Sample Output David    Smith   55    Hello Everyone! 
John   Ark   23    Hello Everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to get you started:

```
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

Set mySheet= ActiveSheet

lastRow = mySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Print #TextFile, "FirstName Person" & CStr(i) & ": " & mySheet.Cells(i,1).Text
    Print #TextFile, "LastName Person" & CStr(i) & ": " & mySheet.Cells(i,2).Text
    Print #TextFile, "Age Person" & CStr(i) & ": " & mySheet.Cells(i,3).Text
    Print #TextFile,     'print a blank line
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! :) is it possible to add double quote inside the " " in Print function? For example Print #TextFile, " "Name" ". and the output should be like "Name"

Comment: Yes, that is regular `string` thingy. You need to escape it: `" ""Name"" "`

Comment: To start a `string` with a quote in the `string` you also escape it: `"""this has a quote before"` or if you only want one quote inside the `string` and nothing else, you put `""""` an escaped quote in quotes. If you want two quotes you escape both: `""""""` Oh, yeah, and don't forget to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Got it :) Another question, for example my cell A2 was assigned to variable FName. Not I have a print function Print #TextFile, "My Firstname: <put value of Fname variable here>".

Comment: You can do that with `Print #Textfile, "My Firstname: " & CStr(Fname)`